# How can I display generators or a minimal generating set with GAP?

Tags: group-theory, gap

The following commands

```
gap> G:=SmallGroup(6,1);
<pc group of size 6 with 2 generators>
gap> GeneratorsOfGroup(G);
[ f1, f2 ]
gap>
```

display the generators of $G$ in a rather abstract way. The command StructureDescription helps to understand the structure of the group, but does not tell anything about generators or generating sets. In particular, how do I get the size of a minimal generating set of some group ?

> How can I display the generators or a minimal generating set more concrete, for example a^2=b^3=ab^2=e or something like that ? $f_1$ and $f_2$ is not helpful to understand the structure of a group.

UPDATE : I just found an answer that could help me. The following commands give
the relations of the group.

```
gap> H:=Image(IsomorphismFpGroup(G));
<fp group of size 6 on the generators [ F1, F2 ]>
gap> RelatorsOfFpGroup(H);
[ F1^2, F2^-1*F1^-1*F2*F1*F2^-1, F2^3 ]
gap>
```

Is this a presentation of the given group ?

Comment: Easy asked a very similar question, but the answers did not tell me how I can display human-readable generators / genrating sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a pc group (polycyclic presentation), `RelatorsOfFpGroup(Range(IsomorphismFpGroup(G)))` will return defining relators in these generators which can be interpreted as either expressing generator powers or generator commutators in terms of "lower order" generators. This can represents *some* semidirect product structure.

Otherwise one would have to find "nice" generators by hand, the question
[Presentation for hand calculation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617928/presentation-for-hand-calculation)
might give a bit of an idea how to do so.

You can compute a minimal (with respect to cardinality) generating set as

```
gap> MinimalGeneratingSet(G);
[ f1, f2 ]
```

(this will work only for solvable groups. In general there is `SmallGeneratingSet` that does not guarantee minimal cardinality), but in this case it will give you the same generators as before.
`MinimalGeneratingSet` will only give a generating set of minimal cardinality -- it is not a generating set with respect to which a presentation would be particularly nice.

Comment: Does that mean that it is impossible to find a minimal generating set of a group with GAP ?

Comment: @Peter No, you can use `MinimalGeneratingSet` (for solvable groups only) or `SmallGeneratingSet`, but these in general are just chosen to be minimal by cardinality and do not satisfy any particular niceness conditions.

Comment: @Peter: also look at `SimplifiedFpGroup` usage [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/774048/)

Comment: @Alex my intent is to give a group, lets say, SmallGroup(16,2) and then calculate a minimal generating set for that group. Can I do this in GAP ?

Comment: @Peter Added remark on minimal generating set.